# ruby here-doc with a loop

Tags: ruby, loops, heredoc

Can you do a loop and  here-doc, something like this:

```
array.each do |ele|
  a=<<-TEXT
   ele
   some stuff
  TEXT
end
```

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking. Can you rephrase? What is the output result that you want to achieve?

Comment: @elusive ok updated, theres no specific output besides the fact that i need to get elements from an array

Comment: Please add some example input and output. I do not understand how the loop and the HERE-doc could possibly be related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
array = %w[one two many]

array.each do |ele|
  a=<<-TEXT
  This is some text and
  this --> #{ele} <-- is the ele!

  TEXT

  puts a
end
```

results in

```
This is some text and
this --> one <-- is the ele!

This is some text and
this --> two <-- is the ele!

This is some text and
this --> many <-- is the ele!
```

Comment: ahh ok, i was putting the "a" on the outside of the loop. That makes sense though. Thanks!

Comment: @steenslag true. Matt wanted to assign a string to `a` in his question; I have randomly added `puts` to get a clue of what was happening :)

Comment: You can still put `puts` outside the loop if you don't assign `a` within the loop and make `each` a `map`. I would even prefer that way.

Comment: Yea, but i need a variable for later on in the code. It's not being printed.